# Why does Python subprocess.check_call fails to launch abc(1).bat? (bracket in filename)

Tags: python, windows, cmd, subprocess

I run into a problem with Python 2.7.6 on Windows 7 x64. Please help check with it.

I have **abc.py**

```
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call('abc(1).bat')

print 'done'
```

**abc(1).bat** has only one line:

```
ver
```

Running abc.py fails to launch abc(1).bat , with error message on CMD console:

```
'abc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test\abc.py", line 3, in <module>
    subprocess.check_call('abc(1).bat')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'abc(1).bat' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

If I do not use brackets in my .bat file name, this problem does not occur. Can someone help explain this?

Comment: What if you also make a file called `abc.bat` which echos some test string?  Does that get called instead?

Comment: Yes. Naming it **abc.bat** instead of **abc(1).bat** works as expected.

Comment: You misunderstood me: I mean use the code you have but while abc.bat also exists.  To see if trying to launch `abc(1).bat` will erroneously invoke abc.bat.  This is mostly a curiosity now, as I imagine @SukritKalra's answer will help fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because even in the command line, running `abc(1).bat` returns an error. It needs to run as `"abc(1).bat"`. If you fix your Python code to.

```
subprocess.check_call('"abc(1).bat"')
```

This works all fine.

The reason for this is stated in a [Microsoft FAQ Question](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/217127).

Comment: Wow, such a big gotcha. But that Microsoft KB217127 does not tell us what semantic is reserved for brackets when they appear in a .bat filename.

Comment: Parantheses are a part of the CMD syntax. As far as I can remember, they are used in looping etc. So, without the strings, CMD gets confused if the parantheses are in the file names or are some constructs.

Comment: Thanks. I realize surrounding my .bat name with double quotes is a good practice as it also cope with space-in-filename issue.

Comment: @JimmChen: does `subprocess.check_call(['abc(1).bat'])` work? (Note: no double quotes and the list argument is used).